# Updating using Z.EntityFramework.Plus is not updating data

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an update method in my UnitOfWork repository like this:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateExpression)
{
     return await dbSet.Where(predicate).UpdateAsync(updateExpression);
}
```

I also have an update method in my logic like this:
where BetSelection has a  Selection Id as a foreign key.

```
private async Task UpdateBetSelections(Table table)
{
     await _unitOfWork.BetSelection
          .UpdateAsync(bs => bs.Selection.TableId == table.Id && bs.Selection.RoundId == table.CurrentRound,
     bs => new BetSelection()
     {
           Status = bs.Selection.Status
     });
}
```

I am trying to update all BetSelection records statuses of a round to the statuses of its corresponding Selections' status. The query is not throwing any error and neither updating the records.

Comment: Not a familiar with this extension. But what you are trying to update Status to the same Status?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes I am trying to update the status of BetSelection record to the status of a Selection record where that selection is a model of BetSelection

Comment: Oh, it is a navigation property... missed that. I think this extension can not process navigation properties. It is hard if you do not have own LINQ translator. I had to propose better extension for that: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Complex types are not supported yet according to [this](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update#limitations)

[Github issue](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/647)

**Original answer**

Unfortunately, looks like there is a bug. I created small repro and it generates following sql. Navigation property is not mentioned.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Status] = B.[Status]
FROM [BetSelections] AS A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[SelectionId], [b].[Status]
FROM [BetSelections] AS [b]
           ) AS B ON A.[Id] = B.[Id]
```

Code to reproduce

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Selection
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BetSelection> Selections { get; set; }
    }

    public class BetSelection
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        public int SelectionId { get; set; }

        public virtual Selection Selection { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Selection> Selections { get; set; }

        public DbSet<BetSelection> BetSelections { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-5PVJ0I5;Database=zefcore-so1;Integrated Security=true");

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            BatchUpdateManager.BatchUpdateBuilder = builder => {
                builder.Executing = c =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.CommandText);
                };
            };

            var db = new AppDbContext();

            var selection = db.Selections.Add(new Selection()
            {
                Status = 1,
            });

            db.BetSelections.Add(new BetSelection()
            {
                Selection = selection.Entity,
                Status = 2,
            });

            db.SaveChanges();

            await db.BetSelections
                .UpdateAsync(x => new BetSelection() { Status = x.Selection.Status });
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you rename parent field to something else, `Status111` in my case, you will get invalid column exception for sql below

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Status] = B.[Status111]
FROM [BetSelections] AS A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[SelectionId], [b].[Status]
FROM [BetSelections] AS [b]
           ) AS B ON A.[Id] = B.[Id]
```